# Fetch the value of a specific key from the hash array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`params = [{id: 1, name: 'hoge'}, {id: 2, name: 'fuga'}]`

I know I can fetch the values of a specific key in this way.

```
params.map{ |u| u.name }
=> ["hoge", "fuga"]
```

But, I wanna do this without block like below,

```
params.map(&:name)
```

If the params is ActiveRecord, I can do in above way. 
Even if params is a hash, please tell me if anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Not a problem: `Hash.define_method(:name) { self[:name] }; params.map(&:name)
#=> ["hoge", "fuga"]`. I should, however, add a qualifier, namely :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using rails, and not vanilla ruby, what you're really looking for is `pluck`!

```
params = [{id: 1, name: 'hoge'}, {id: 2, name: 'fuga'}]
params.pluck(:name)

=> ["hoge", "fuga"]
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
params = [{id: 1, name: 'hoge'}, {id: 2, name: 'fuga'}]
```

As emaillenin says, you can do:

```
params.map { |p| OpenStruct.new(p) }.map(&:name)
```

But, if you do:

```
params.map { |p| OpenStruct.new(p).name }
```

You save an iteration and seven key strokes. And if you do:

```
params.map { |p| p[:name] }
```

You save an additional 14 characters. But, you can't do:

```
params.map{ |u| u.name }
```

If `u` is a `Hash`. Nor can you do:

```
params.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params = [{id: 1, name: 'hoge'}, {id: 2, name: 'fuga'}]
params.map { |p| OpenStruct.new(p) }.map(&:name)

# ["hoge", "fuga"]
```